# Детеныш ламы

Tags: лексика

Вопрос детский. Но все-таки, как назвать детеныша ламы? Ламенок? Ламчик?))

Comment: Насчет суффикса -чик- - а Вы можете привести примеры использования его для образования названий детенышей животных. По мне так, зайчик - это маленький заяц, а не обязательно, что зайчонок..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Звучит немного странновато и непривычно, но всех парнокопытных детенышей биологи называют телятами. Можно еще сказать *детеныш, жеребенок ламы*.

Comment: Отнюдь не странно. "Теленок" в отношении *крупных* рогатых и безрогих скотов - вполне нормально. Но лама-то размером ближе к козлам, поэтому есть определенные сомнения. Вот жеребенок - это как раз непарнокопытный.

Comment: Не спорю, что жеребенок - это непарнокопытное. Поэтому и странно такое название. Как по мне, то правильнее сказать "детеныш ламы".

Answer (score 1):

Не всем животным повезло с именами детенышей. Особенно это касается тех, которые не характерны для мест распространения русского языка, тут вот недавно долго зебру вспоминали. Хотя у неё-то - жеребёнок, к бабке не ходи. ))
Поэтому пусть он останется детёнышем ламы. Хотя по общей модели получилось бы, наверное (*)ламёнок. Суффикс -онок (-ёнок) наиболее продуктивен в подобных случаях.

Comment: А продуктивность суффикса зависит ли от того изначальное заимствованное ли слово или нет? Ну, например, кот (котёнок), медведь (медвежонок), заяц (зайчонок) и пр. - явно русские слова. По крайней мере они обладают весьма долгой историей, чтобы мы могли считать так. А вот лама, зебра, антилопа и пр. - все заимствованные слова. Появились в языке явно не раньше эпохи великий открытий, когда путешественники встретили этих животных...

Comment: Не задумывался. Вряд ли это как-то связано. "-ёнок" способно к словообразованию даже с "незаимствованными" и "несловами": пингвинёнок, негритёнок, свинёнок, щурёнок, бочонок... Не даром Щерба его даже в "Глокую куздру" вставил...

Comment: А бочонок причем?

Answer (score 1):

Классический вариант всё же детёныш ламы, по-другому его никто нигде не называет.Если поразмышлять о "возможности"называния, думаю, ближе всего будет ягнёнок. Лама  - животное из верблюжьих,но по внешности похоже на большую овцу, когда путешественники увидели ламу в Перу, они так и называли её большой "овцой",она и блеяла как овца, так что вполне можно назвать детёныша ягнёнком. Только это будет не научно, потому что порода всё же верблюжья, только горба нет.

Answer (score 0):

> Насчет суффикса -чик- - а Вы можете привести примеры использования его для образования названий детенышей животных. По мне так, зайчик - это маленький заяц...

gecube, в слове "зайчик" суффикс не -чик-, а -ик-.